# Change output directory of generated code in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, code-generation

Project contains annotation processor which generates java code during compilation. By default, gradle outputs generated source files into `build/classes` directory. That causes some problems with discovery of  newly generated source files by IntelliJ.

Is there any straightforward way of configuring gradle to output source files into another directory? For example `$buildDir/gen/main/java` or `$buildDir/build/generated/main/java`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is an option for java compiler which allows to customize output directory for generated java sources ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)).

> -s dir
>
> Specify the directory where to place generated source files. The
>   directory must already exist; javac will not create it. If a class is
>   part of a package, the compiler puts the source file in a subdirectory
>   reflecting the package name, creating directories as needed. For
>   example, if you specify -s C:\mysrc and the class is called
>   com.mypackage.MyClass, then the source file will be placed in
>   C:\mysrc\com\mypackage\MyClass.java.

Example of `build.gradle`

```
compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs << "-s"
    options.compilerArgs << "$projectDir/generated/java"

    doFirst {
        // make sure that directory exists
        file(new File(projectDir, "/generated/java")).mkdirs()
    }
}

clean.doLast {
    // clean-up directory when necessary
    file(new File(projectDir, "/generated")).deleteDir()
}

sourceSets {
    generated {
        java {
            srcDir "$projectDir/generated/java"
        }
    }
}
```

This code snippet does next:

- creates and specifies directory as output for generated code
- deletes generated sources if clean task is invoked
- adds new source set

## Update

Use gradle [apt plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/net.ltgt.apt) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the solution - it works great for me, with a tweak in that I prefer to put the generated files in `$project.buildDir/generated/java`, as that means you don't need to worry about changing how clean works. Also, there doesn't seem to be a need to actually add a source set, that works anyway.

Comment: If any one else runs into a java compile error on subsequent recompiles .. add the following to the doFirst block:
`GFileUtils.cleanDirectory(directory); ` .. depending on your version of gradle you may need to use `FileUtils.cleanDirectory`

Comment: @PetterMåhlén, why the sourceSet config is optional? gradle needs it to build jar which includes the generated classes.

Comment: @Sunnyday I don't know, Gradle is largely a mystery to me. Just reporting my experiences. :)

Comment: Any declaration about the Update part? how to use apt plugin?!!

Answer (score 9):

Simply specify value for **project.buildDir** property in your build.gradle file:

```
project.buildDir = '/gen/main/java'
```

This will put all generated build files to the `<project_root>/gen/main/java` folder.

Comment: This is not the best solution, since not only generated, but also build output of compiler will be placed in that directory (.class files and other stuff which you don't want to be in your source code).

Answer (score 3):

By default generated Java files are under `$generatedFilesBaseDir/$sourceSet/$builtinPluginName`, where `$generatedFilesBaseDir` is `$buildDir/generated/source/proto` by default, and is configurable. E.g.,

```
protobuf {
 ...
  generatedFilesBaseDir = "$projectDir/src/generated"
}
```

The subdirectory name, which is by default `$builtinPluginName`, can also be changed by setting the `outputSubDir` property in the builtins or plugins block of a task configuration within `generateProtoTasks` block (see previous section). E.g.,

```
{
  task ->
  task.plugins {
    grpc {
    // Write the generated files under
    // "$generatedFilesBaseDir/$sourceSet/grpcjava"
    outputSubDir = 'grpcjava'
    }
  }
}
```

to see [github protobuf-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin#change-where-files-are-generated)